# How to check if a room exists before sending a message to a socket?

Tags: typescript, socket.io

```
broadcastToSpecificUser(message: any): void {
    if(message.username){
        this.io.sockets.in(message.username).emit("eventArrived", message);
    }else{
        this.io.sockets.emit("eventArrived", message);
   }
}
```

I am trying to send a message to only the sockets of a particular room. "message" is an event object in which there is a property called username which I am using to check if a room exists.How should I modify the above code?

Answer (score 6):

Since `rooms` is a `Map`, `io.sockets.adapter.rooms["room name"]` returns undefined. Instead, I use

```js
io.sockets.adapter.rooms.get("room name")
```

Comment: or io.sockets.adapter.rooms.has('room name')

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
if(io.sockets.adapter.rooms["room name"])
{
     //if room exist
}
```

Answer (score 0):

An option is to use a ternary operator to define what object needs to emit your message, something like this:

```
broadcastToSpecificUser(message: any): void {
  const emitter = message.username ? this.sockets.in(message.username) : this.io.sockets;
  emitter.emit("eventArrived", message);
}
```